# Google Embedded Map has a style property forced to it

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, iframe

I have page where all I need is a simple, full-width embedded google map. When I set the custom size of the map to 1980px x 240px, and put the iframe on my page, the width of the map is 1200px by default.

When I open Chrome DevTools window and find the iframe there, there is a style forced to the iframe, that is not in the original iframe I pasted from google maps.

The website is build on Wordpress. Link: https://zubar-litomerice.cz/

The original iframe:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d12061.22772549553!2d14.12158474671251!3d50.54234042444077!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x47097f6dc0e9276d%3A0xa7e584e5a1a520cc!2sHavlov%C3%A1+Hana+MUDr.!5e0!3m2!1sen!2scz!4v1533828352977" width="1980" height="240" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Forced style:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d12061.22772549553!2d14.12158474671251!3d50.54234042444077!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x47097f6dc0e9276d%3A0xa7e584e5a1a520cc!2sHavlov%C3%A1+Hana+MUDr.!5e0!3m2!1sen!2scz!4v1533828352977" width="1980" height="240" frameborder="0" style="border: 0px; width: 1200px; height: 145px;" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

I have searched for answers before asking and could not find anything, but maybe you can help me find the answer I am looking for.

Comment: You put the iframe in a  div that has a width of 1170px. Since you're running WP I'd assume this is the theme that's doing it. You can also see what the content_width global is set to.

Comment: @j08691 Yes, thank you for your answer. I was able to find out where the problem was, the theme had the iframe property styled in the main theme stylesheet.